# MySQL IF THEN AS Syntax

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures, while-loop, alias

I'm trying to populate a table via stored procedure as such:

```
SET @resultsCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA);
SET @i = 0;  

WHILE @i < @resultscount DO
  SET @revNum = 0;
  INSERT INTO tableB (Name, revNumber, Meta)
  SELECT
    name AS Name,
    (IF @i=0 THEN  
      SELECT @revNum;
    ELSE IF <condition> THEN
      SET @revNum = @revNum +1;
      SELECT @revNum;
    ELSE
      SELECT @revNum;  
    END IF) AS revNumber,
    meta AS Meta
  FROM tableA;
  SET @i = @i + 1;
END WHILE;
```

However, the above IF statement fails due to syntax errors. I have tried to use the IF function, or case statements instead, but they seem to only allow a single statement to be executed after each condition, and I need to do a SET and then a SELECT in two separate statements.

Answer (score 0):

By using `ELSE IF`, you start a new `IF` statement, that you never `END IF` (you only `END IF` once). Change that to [`ELSEIF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html):

```
IF @i=0 THEN  
  SELECT @revNum;
ELSEIF <condition> THEN
  SET @revNum = @revNum +1;
  SELECT @revNum;
ELSE
  SELECT @revNum;  
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use procedural features like `IF THEN` within queries; instead try the query equivalents, like `IF(<condition>, <true case>, <false case>)` or `CASE WHEN <condition1> THEN <value1|expression1> WHEN <condition2> THEN <value2|expression2> ELSE <valueX|expressionX> END`.

Basically, if you have a `;` within a query, that is not just part of a string, then there is going to be a problem.

---

In your case I would translate all that to something like this:

`IF(@i=0, @revNum, IF(<condition>, @revNum := @revNum + 1, @revNum)) AS revNumber`

or

`@revNum = @revNum + IF(@i <> 0 AND <condition>,1,0) AS revNumber`

The first version is a more direct translation, but the second is probably safer as you can some weird behavior it you are not careful with @/session variable assignment in conditional expressions.